# Best way to hack the return type on an implemented method?

Tags: java

I'm implementing a service through a maven dependency which takes data and spits it out at another virtual location, provided that it conforms with its strict type requirements. However, I've swapped out one of the fields (let's call the field `Buzz` and my implementation of it `Buzzer`) and am wondering if I can make this work with the rest of the service.

The service is a call to a factory which requires the type `Buzz` and the diff between `Buzz` and `Buzzer` is a few extra added member fields. Is there any hack I can do to make the factory accept `Buzzer`? Looking through the code, the service does not seem to do anything which would be dependent on the hashcode of `Buzz` being correct.

EDIT: Examples

```
class Buzz
{ 
   public String ID
   public String name
   public String title
   public Iterable<profile> profiles


   public myConstructor(String ID, String name, String title, Iterable profile)
   {
   this.var = var;
   }
}
```

and

```
class Buzzer
{
   public String ID
   public String name
   public String title
   public profile profiles

   public myConstructor(String ID, String name, String title, profile profiles)
   {
   this.var = var;
   }
}
```

where `profile` is a defined object

Comment: If you're certain that the framework doesn't care about those extra fields on `Buzzer`, I'm thinking that you could have `Buzzer` extend `Buzz`.

Comment: Can't you have `Buzzer` extend `Buzz`?

Comment: I tried that, but I got "There is no default constructor available in `Buzz` "

Comment: I think this question is a little unclear and could benefit from more specifics (like a short program which contains some classes and fields forming an example of the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have Buzzer extend Buzz, that would be ideal.

If you can't however (for example if it is from a 3rd party library and declared as a final class), then the hack solution would be to "acquire" a Buzz instance (that will depend on the specific scenareo.. need more info to be more specific).  And then modify its buzz property through reflection.

Something like this:

```
String buzz = null;  // Assuming Buzz field is a string in this example
Field fBuzz = null;
try
{
    Class<?> cBuzz = theBuzzInstance.getClass();
    fBuzz = cBuzz.getDeclaredField( "buzz" );
    fBuzz.setAccessible( true );
    buzz = ( String ) fBuzz.get( theBuzzInstance );

    String newBuzz = "Hacked!";
    fBuzz.set( theBuzzInstance, newBuzz );
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    // TODO: Error handling
}
```